# Why setState changes also the props which i added to the state before

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

Scenario:

I have two components: X and Y. Component Y is the child of component X.

inside X:

```
<Y data={FormObject} />
```

Inside the constructor of component Y, I add the prop data (FormObject) to the state of Y which works well. Now after that, if I change the state it affects the props. How? When I close component Y and reopen it I see that the last state is showing up. FormObject isn't like how it was at the beginning. This is because objects are reference types right?

Is there a solution for this? The only solution i found is to do somthing like this:

Inside constructor of Y:

```
const { data } = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props);
```

Does it seem like JSON.parse() or JSON.stringify() changed the reference by making a copy with a different memory number?

Is there a better way of doing this instead of the mentioned solution?

Comment: why r are you copying props to state on the first place ?

Comment: @ibtsam I'm using Redux and the props data comes from the store. The object i get back from the store is contains some key/value pairs which i changed to a form inputfield/label. So if i want to call a onChange on one of the inputfields i don't want to change the store instead i change the state of the component to make two way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `FormObject` has no child object or array, you can fix that by using object destructor like below:

```
const data = { ...this.props.data }; // it's a kind of shallow copy
```

But if it has some object or array in it, it won't prevent mutations.

So you need to deep copy using `JSON.pares(JSON.stringify(data))` or Recursive method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It has objects in it.

Comment: @J.Adam Then I am not sure but IMO, using `JSON.pares(JSON.stringify(data))` is  good idea. In fact, I always do deep copy with that method. :)

Answer (score 1):

ok if you have to have new copy of the props in your state you can use some library for cloning the deeply nested object, you  can use [deepClone](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) method from lodash.

I would also recommend taking a look at [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) from react documentation

hope it helps.